# Does this puzzle really not exist already?

Tags: puzzle-creation

I have invented a puzzle about the start of the year that I believe is new. But is it really? I call it Begriddled.

It uses a grid of characters that you join according to a sequence (either given or to be partially or fully deduced by the solver) to reveal a hidden design (generally text or a picture).

Here's an example I've used in showing how it works:

[image: Begriddled puzzle example]

The rules are:

Rule 0: Dots are dots. You do nothing with them except pencil them in. They are the only character that does NOT obey Rule 1.

Rule 1: Join all pairs of horizontally and vertically adjacent characters that are the same.

Rule 2: Join all pairs of horizontally, vertically, and diagonally adjacent characters that appear next to each other in the circular sequence.

The "logic" version is exactly the same except you must deduce part or the whole of the sequence from additional rules.

Here's an example of the logic version which while clearly not so simple is intentionally not so hard either.

Is anyone aware of anything like this already out there (except, of course, for my own examples which are easy to find by search for the name)?

[image: Begriddled logic puzzle example]

The result looks best if you use thick bold lines right across the grid of characters, for example drawing a single thick line right across the stack of three 5's in the above.

(My avatar is an example of a simple puzzle resulting in a picture.)

Comment: I can't be certain, but I'm pretty familiar with a lot of logic puzzles, and I've never seen anything like this.

Comment: Thanks @Deusovi. It seemed such a simple idea in a way but was unable to find anything like it online. But who knows what might be lurking in old magazines and books.

Comment: Fun to solve. I finished the first and most of the second during my commute home from work. (Riding the bus - don't try to solve puzzles while driving!)

Comment: Thanks, @DanielMathias. I'm not sure if it's OK to mention (and in two minds - but what if people feel cheated if I don't?) that having come up with this originally months ago I'm well into compiling a couple of books and have a Kickstarter campaign with a week left. Can find with search for the puzzle name if interested. I am claiming to be the inventor which is one thing on a website that can be fixed quickly, but have this lurking fear that as soon as I've published it will turn out there's something very similar I haven't found. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a picture of my solution:

> [image: my solution]

Comment: I don't have time to do a proper write-up for the logic of the second puzzle. I may add it in the next few days.

Comment: Yes. I know you don't need confirmation from me! Upvoted but can't accept as the answer of course because that wasn't the question :)